# Mattermost unable to connect to the SMTP server -tcp [::1]:10025

Tags: tcp, smtp, mattermost

I am trying to reset my password with .mmctl --local and I get this error everytime

"level":"error","msg":"Failed to send password reset email successfully.","caller":"web/context.go:115","path":"/api/v4/users/password/reset/send","request_id":"feyqb3sc83nc5dm7kwocshag4e","ip_addr":"","user_id":"","method":"POST","err_where":"SendPasswordReset","http_code":500,"error":"SendPasswordReset: Failed to send password reset email successfully., err=unable to connect to the SMTP server: dial tcp [::1]:10025: connect: connection refused"}

I checked the SMTP settings with the help of some answers to similar problems, but nothing changed. The error message is always the same.
Help!